# Microsoft Word: Text space automatically being introduced when inserting citations. How to stop this?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I am using MS-Word 2010 professional and trying to submit a document to my professor, and he requires citations to hug the text.

My problem:

[image]

The top-right red arrow points to me highlighting the space between a citation and the end of the text. I have not been able to delete, alter, or affect this space in any way. I need it removed.

The bottom-left red arrow points to a non-highlighted example where the space is more readily apparent.

I have a script that can turn the references into superscript, but even then the space is noticeable. I am using the Insert Citation command (visible in the toolbar at the top of the picture above). I have 70 references in maybe 100 different places over an 80 page document, so switching the mode of citation (eg. to Endnote) isn't much of an option at this point. Can I just change MS's formatting away from arbitrarily adding a space?

Thank you so much for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is not a real space. If this is a real space character the below answer is not relevant.

I don't know the reason this happens, but I have found possible workarounds.

1. When I copy/paste the text to a brand new document the space around reference disappears.
2. Another method I found is to save the document in Word 97-2003 format  (DOC), and then save it again as Word 2010 (DOCX). After this the space is no longer there, but of course for complex documents there may be some issues related to conversion.

I suspect the problem is in Normal.dot template used for creation of the original document. Comparing original document and the document created after DOCX->DOC->DOCX conversion shows only changes related to styles used.

If the above workarounds don't solve the problem try repeating them on another computer (problem in my case was in a document I received from someone).